# Python serial port read data in linux - terminal didn't display the output

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, fpga, pyserial

I am trying to read data from the serial port of the Artix-7 FPGA. If I read the data from Putty it shows me the data. The data is a 4-Byte hexadecimal numbers. Like;

000FFFFA

0000FCA0

000078CC
........ almost more than 10,000 lines data...
But I want to read the data from the Python script the script mentioned below should work; it connected to the port but shows only the empty strings. Seems like Ubuntu terminal didn't display the data. But if I didn't display the data and only save it, again no data. Any idea !!!!!!

#

```
!/usr/bin/python

import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE 
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.timeout = None         
ser.timeout = 1              
ser.xonxoff = False    
ser.rtscts = False    
ser.dsrdtr = False       
ser.writeTimeout = 2    
try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
        ser.flushInput() 
        ser.flushOutput()
        time.sleep(0.5)  
        numOfLines = 0

        f=open('signature.txt','w+')

        while True:
          response = ser.readline()
          f=ser.write(response)
          print response
          numOfLines = numOfLines + 1


        f.close()
        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be making those `flushInput()` and `flushOutput()` calls? In version 3.0 of pySerial, those methods have been renamed `reset_input_buffer()` and `reset_output_buffer()`. In the case of the former, the documentation says it will "Flush input buffer, discarding all it’s contents.". This might be why `ser.readline()` isn't capturing anything.

Comment: No luck. I changed flushinput() and flushoutput() to the reset_input_buffer() and reset_output_buffer() but still getting the same

Comment: Have you tried removing them altogether? My thinking was not that the functions needed to be renamed, but that they are deleting all of the data that you are hoping to capture.

Comment: yes I tried but very confused now why the code gives me blank lines

Comment: I figure it out the readline() didn't work it returned me the null. readline() . suppose to read. any help?